# JS parsing error with vue and vite even when plugin is installed and project is in typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I keep getting this error, even though I have the plugin installed:

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. Install @vitejs/plugin-vue to handle .vue files.
/Documents/Code/JS/Quoridor/client/src/App.vue:3:10
1  |  <script setup lang="ts">
2  |  import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
3  |  </script>
   |           ^
4  |  
5  |  <template>
```

the project was setup with vite and nothing except the file structure has been touched, i tried to run it using npm run dev and the project is in typescript.

This is how my vite.config.ts is setup so it should be working, since it calls the plugin.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()]
})
```

and my App.vue is just the standard app.vue that is generated when you create a new project i just created the project, so nothing has been changed except the file structure.

This is my file structure

```
│   .gitignore
│   index.html
│   package.json
├───.idea
├───.vscode
├───client
│   │   package-lock.json
│   │   package.json
│   │   tsconfig.json
│   │   vite-env.d.ts
│   │   vite.config.ts
│   ├───node_modules
│   ├───public
│   │       vite.svg
│   └───src
│       │   App.vue
│       │   main.ts
│       │   style.css
│       │   vue-shims.d.ts
│       ├───assets
│       ├───components
│       └───router
├───common
├───server
│   │   package-lock.json
│   │   package.json
│   │   tsconfig.node.json
│   ├───controllers
│   ├───models
│   ├───node_modules
│   └───routes
```

ive already tried to delete node modules and reinstalling it and checked all the paths are correct and nothing seems to be wrong.